# Triosephosphate isomerase deficiency

Tags: physiology, enzymes, hematology, glucose, pathophysiology

> Triose phosphate isomerase deficiency, a rare condition, is the only glycolytic enzymopathy that is lethal. This deficiency is characterized by severe hemolytic anemia and neurodegeneration.

How can I relate this enzyme deficiency to hemolysis?

---

My attempt:

1- Accumulation of DHAP is causing intracellular fluid to be more osmotic leading to cell bursting.( Then why don't we see the same in outer cells?)

2-Lack of glucose may lead to less ATP production, Na/K pumps work less, thus disturbing membrane potential, which finally may cause hyper-osmic ICF and then henolysis. ( But why don't RBC take twice the amount of glucose?)

---

Source: Biochemistry 8th edition by Jeremy M. Berg John L. Tymoczko Gregory J. Gatto, Jr. Lubert Stryer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike most of the cells in a human body, erythrocytes (or red blood cells) don't have mitochondria (because they are basically O<sub>2</sub> carriers), and don't perform Krebs Cycle or Oxidative Phosphorylation. Therefore, they depend *exclusively* on glycolysis to produce their ATPs.

According to the *Genetics Home Reference* (from the NIH, National Institutes of Health) page about triosephosphate isomerase deficiency:

> The anemia in this condition begins in infancy. Since the anemia results from the premature breakdown of red blood cells (hemolysis), it is known as hemolytic anemia [...] TPI1 gene mutations lead to the production of unstable enzymes or enzymes with decreased activity. As a result, glycolysis is impaired and cells have a decreased supply of energy. Red blood cells **depend solely** on the breakdown of glucose for energy, and without functional glycolysis, red blood cells die earlier than normal. (emphasis mine)

Thus, since erythrocytes depend solely on glycolysis as energy source, there is a marked accumulation of DHAP toxic sub-products (Ahmed et al., 2003).

Sources:

- Reference, G. (2017). triosephosphate isomerase deficiency. [online] Genetics Home Reference. Available at: https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/condition/triosephosphate-isomerase-deficiency#genes [Accessed 16 Jul. 2017].
- [Ahmed, N., Battah, S., Karachalias, N., Babaei-Jadidi, R., Horányi, M., Baróti, K., Hollan, S. and Thornalley, P. (2003). Increased formation of methylglyoxal and protein glycation, oxidation and nitrosation in triosephosphate isomerase deficiency. Biochimica et Biophysica Acta (BBA) - Molecular Basis of Disease, 1639(2), pp.121-132](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14559119).

Comment: But why don't they utilise twice the amount of glucose?

Comment: In the absence of TIM half of the G3P is present for carrying glycolysis.

Comment: G3P dehydrogenase can act on it to form glycerol-3-phosphate, which can be used for lipid synthesis.

Comment: Well, I shared a source that clearly explains the issue. I believe the best idea is just deleting my answer.

Comment: please add this to your answer , https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14559119

Comment: the main culprit here seems to be formation of advanced glycation products.